# Iterate and flatten an Array of Struct types in a Dataset using Apache Spark :Java

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset with Schema as below

```
 root
 |-- collectorId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- generatedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- managedNeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- neAlert: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- advisory: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- equipmentType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- headlineName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fieldNotice: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- caveat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- distributionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hwEoX: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- bulletinName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- equipmentType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- swEoX: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- bulletinHeadline: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- equipmentType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- recordType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceNeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourcePartyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceSubPartyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- wfid: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to get the fields inside the "element". In order to do this I have done an explode on the array to flatten this.

```
Dataset<Row> alert = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("C:\\Users\\LearningAndDevelopment\\\\merge\\data1\\sample.json");

Seq<String> droppedColumns = scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("neAlert"));

Dataset<Row> alertjson = alert.withColumn("exploded_advisory", explode(col("neAlert.advisory"))).withColumn("exploded_fn", explode(col("neAlert.fieldNotice"))).withColumn("exploded_swEoX", explode(col("neAlert.swEoX"))).withColumn("exploded_hwEox", explode(col("neAlert.hwEoX"))).drop(droppedColumns);

alertjson.printSchema();
```

I got the final JSON as below

```
root
 |-- collectorId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- generatedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- managedNeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- recordType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceNeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourcePartyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceSubPartyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- wfid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_advisory: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- equipmentType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- headlineName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_fn: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- caveat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- distributionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_swEoX: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bulletinHeadline: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- equipmentType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded_hwEox: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bulletinName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- equipmentType: string (nullable = true)
```

But, the above method created all duplicate records flattened with data in the first element of each JSON array. Each array can have so many elements. How can i flatten the JSON arrays without loosing the data integrity.

Comment: do all arrays have the same length?

Comment: not necessarily.

Comment: what should happen in that case? should be short array be filled with nulls to match the longest size?

Comment: yep that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the nested `json` with `.` dot operator first and use `explode` for each nested field.

```
Dataset<Row> alertjson = alert
    .withColumn("exploded_advisory", explode(col("neAlert.advisory")))
    .withColumn("exploded_fn", explode(col("neAlert.fieldNotice")))
    .withColumn("exploded_swEoX", explode(col("neAlert.swEoX")))
    .withColumn("exploded_hwEox", explode(col("neAlert.hwEoX")));
```

If you want each field `explode` as individual then you have to explode separately which created multiple dataframes

```
// for advisory
Dataset<Row> alertjson = alert
    .withColumn("exploded_advisory", explode(col("neAlert.advisory")))

DataSet<Row> fieldNorice = alert
    .withColumn("exploded_fn", explode(col("neAlert.fieldNotice")))
```

Drop the unrequired columns and should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm!!